# TYPO3 backend user right for columns

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I would like to assign BE User rights to specific columns in BE Layout (Field colPos): A usergroup shall not be able to edit one column. 
Any ideas?

Comment: For all backend layouts at once or just for single backend layouts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use condition in page tsconfig:

```
[usergroup = 2]
mod {
    web_layout {
        BackendLayouts {
            standard {
                config {
                    backend_layout {
                        rows {
                            1 {
                                columns {
                                    1 {
                                        colPos = 
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
[global]
```

Comment: Yes this works, thanks a lot! But it requires configuration of backend layouts by PageTS as well. On a server with backend layout records, they have to be tranformed to PageTS before. https://www.braune-digital.com/blog/typo3-backend-layouts-ueber-page-tsconfig-in-dateien-auslagern/